# Can a Flutter/Web App be compiled such that Dart code is available at debug time in a browser

Tags: flutter, debugging, web

Friends

Is it possible to build a flutter web app such that the Dart code that generated the JavaScript is available in the browser?

We are building a Flutter/Web app.

It relies on accessing data from an HTTPS API.

We are in a dilemma when we start to deploy it:

- When running in situ   the code is obfuscated.  The generated JavaScript is all that is available
- Running locally is possible.  `flutter run -d chrome` but we have to mock the API and we have to reproduce the "in situ" environment allowing many opportunities for new errors.  We cannot access the APIs because CORS.  Making changes to the API server is not an option

One solution (we have not tried yet) is  to use a proxy on the development machine to access the API.  This is better than mocking, but is still a step removed from the environment.

Currently we rely on print statements, outputting to the browser console.

Comment: The `--source-maps` argument to the compiler should help.  Using that I can see the source files in the devtools, but I cannot access them

Comment: I have been following this up with the good people at Github/flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134498. Over there there is more clarity abouot how I have `--source-maps` failing